# Is it possible to implement two factors in OTP authentication for LDAP central authentication server

Tags: linux, ldap, redhat, openldap, rhel8

I develop central the authentication server using OpenLDAP for Redhat. Now I need to implement two-factor authentication for it. Is it possible to implement two-factor authentication on the LDAP server? What kind of method should I use if I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

Mainly there are implementations with which users enter their password and OTP in one input field.

Two examples:

- OpenLDAP overlay [slapo-otp](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-otp) in OpenLDAP 2.5+
- my own [OATH-LDAP](https://oath-ldap.stroeder.com/) using external bind listener demons via [slapd-sock](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-sock) used as overlay

Note that *slapo-otp* also uses OATH-LDAP's schema and has it hard-coded in the overlay code. So loading overlay *slapo-otp* or [oath-ldap.schema](https://code.stroeder.com/OATH-LDAP/oath-ldap-openldap/src/branch/main/schema/oath-ldap.schema) is mutually exclusive. Keep this in mind when experimenting with these solutions.